# Indecomposable quiver representations

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Is there are any way to found indecomposable representation of a given quiver explicitely if it's dimention vector is given?

Comment: Literally, no, because there are several representations with the same dimension - for example, all the vertex simple representations have dimension $1$. But maybe you mean "dimension vector"?

Comment: @MattPressland Yes, I mean dimension vector, thank you.

Comment: Still there are in general several indecomposable representations with a given dimension vector. Do you want a way of finding one representation with a given dimension vector or of finding all of them? And do you mind which field you're working over?

Comment: In case wich I'm considering it's known that such representation is unique(it's maximal indecomposable representation of $E_8$). I'm working over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments I'm assuming you are talking about an indecomposable representation of a representation finite quiver (i.e. Dynkin quiver).

Probably not the most efficient way, but one way to do it is to use the knitting algorithm for the Auslander-Reiten quiver. For this you start with the simple projective modules for your quiver (for which you have the representations), then in each step you first radical inclusions $\operatorname{rad} P\to P$, which you also have. And as a second step you compute the cokernel of the direct sum of all the maps starting in the earliest module you have constructed so far. Since you are in the representation finite case, you will have constructed every indecomposable projective after a finite number of steps (for $E_8$ unfortunately $120$ steps are necessary, to arrive at the maximal indecomposable representation you probably need half of them, since I assume it will be in the middle of the Auslander-Reiten quiver).

Comment: I believe someone must have some data (or a program) on this; the problem is finding the correct person to ask for it.  I also think it is worth going through Assem-Simon-Skowronski book chapter VIII to see if there is a quicker way (as there are exercises in that chapter which also ask for position of $E_8$-modules with given dimension vectors).  The still-developing QPA package of GAP should also be able to do a lot of computations for us, as I see that they have implemented the procedure to compute predecessor of a module in AR-quiver.

Comment: I would ask Solberg on a computer implementation, he should know. If you have a procedure to compute the predecessor of a module, then you just have to determine which $\tau^{-1}$-shift of which injective your module is. This you can do by performing the knitting procedure just on dimension vectors, which is much easier. I did that once for one orientation of $E_8$, I was finished by the end of the lunch break.